# Layout on Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: android, layout, screen, samsung-mobile

I have a weird issue that only occurs on the Samsung Galaxy Note.

I have landscape and portrait layouts , in normal and large , as per : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

On all phone so far it uses the normal and the tablets 7inch and 10 inch use the large layout (which was designed for tablets) and all is ok.

However the Samsung Galaxy Note is using the large layout (and from it's screen size would indicate so) - but the layout is a complete mess as it does not seem to be large enough display to show the tablet UI.

What is the exact screen combo for a Galaxy note ? , do I need to define a different density large layout to work with it ?

I am also suspecting it is incorrectly reporting to the app it's size like previous Samsung products.

Not owning one and not able to borrow one I have to appeal to you guys to help me out :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is what you will see on the original Galaxy Note (shipped with Gingerbread)

- Screen pixel density (dpi) - xhdpi
- Screen size - large
- Screen aspect - long

Most of the other tablets (7 inch and 10.1 inch tablets) are mdpi.

This device will pick values from the large resource category since size takes precedence over density.

After the ICS update, the device classifies itself as below.

- Screen pixel density (dpi) - xhdpi
- Screen size - normal
- Screen aspect - not long

Comment: Can we design separate layout folder for Samsung galaxy notes. If yes then what would be the name of that folder is `layout-800*1200` will be correct.

Comment: howcome it uses the normal layout?

Comment: ICS reports back as a Normal size screen and 2.3 Gingerbread reports back as a Large size screen. We had to create a layout named layout-large-port-xhdpi-1280x800 for the Note.

Comment: i am using layout-sw320dp ,which is being used by Galaxy note, but the Galaxy Nexus also uses this folder that makes the layout wrong how do i put the proper layout of each?

Comment: that layout folder doesn't called by the system, im compiling from 2.2 and running it to ICS,before it was being called when run from Gingerbread.

Comment: I tested on a device, Galaxy Note with 2.3 os is "Not long"

Comment: @BerniePerez, is there a reason why you wouldn't just use layout-large-xhdpi-1280x800 vs layout-large-port-xhdpi-1280x800?

Answer (score 2):

Galaxy Note is 1280x800 and dpi 320 according to http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/13711-samsung-galaxy-note-emulator.html