# Force device to get resources from a resource folder

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, galaxy-tab

I know that this behaviour is not expected nor standard, but I'm curous whether it can be achieved.
Google also realized that the normal-large-xlarge scheme is not the best one, so it's deprecated **from** Android 3.2. (layout-swXXXdp would be the best choice for me)

However, there are devices under 3.2 which I have to support, and can misbehave because this system.

**Main problem:**

Galaxy Note 1 and Galaxy tab 1 (and other devices with same specs) choose the resources from the same `layout-large` folder. But reasonably I need to make different layouts under 7 inch and above 7inch screens. I know that I could make a seperate folder for "exception devices" (like layout-large-xhdpi-1280x800 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711877/layout-on-samsung-galaxy-note)), but then I would have to maintain several almost (or exact) same xml files in different folders just because these certain devices.

So the goal would be to maintain only one xml package (folder) for under-7inch-devices, and one for above-7inch devices. I know that there are tricks such as:

1. naming the xml-s differently (main.xml and main-large.xml), and decide in code which to choose, but even devices can't decide about themselves from code, how large are them exactly (for example 7 inch tablets can give back from 6.8 to 7.8 inch scale). Also, I would like to use the more "androidy" way with resource folders.
2. maintain the exception folders as i mentioned. `layout`, `layout-large`, `layout-specifictags1`, `layout-specifictags2` and the list can widen. Also specifictags1, tags2 and normal has the exact same xml files, but needed for devices not to choose from the `layout-large`. The whole reason is to avoid this.
3. (***EDIT***) An idea of using aliases came up by @Joe Malin. Unfortunatly I can't make an alias named main.xml in `layout-large-xhdpi-1280x800` that refers to main.xml in `layout`, because it refers to self then (making infinite loop). So i would have to maintain a fakemain.xml in `layout-large-xhdpi-1280x800` that refers to main.xml which only exists in `layout`. But then i also need a fakemain.xml in `layout`, because then i don't have to care about the layout from code and use only the fakemain.xml which is an alias. However *this solution* still ***could*** work, but is not working in practice, unfortunatly. If I have a a fakemain.xml in `layout`, `layout-large` and `layout-large-xhdpi-1280x800` for galaxy note, then the alias points to the `layout-large` one, and I achieved nothing by using the alias.

**Question:**

layout-sw600dp concept would grant me the best and needed behaviour, but it's not supported under API level 13.

- Is there a way to force a device to choose from this folder, or to write over its variable (with java reflection? - I know that's pretty bad) to behave like normal screen not large?
- Is there a way to maintain only two xml package (folder):

  - one for under-7inch-devices,
  - and one for above-7inch devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the best solution, I think. Somehow i didn't notice, that there are two types of aliases; the one that @Joe Malin [linked](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources), and [this type](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters).

The first type was not the solution unfortunatly, but the second one is exactly what I was looking for, and the developer page describes the solution as I needed:

> res/layout/main.xml: single-pane layout
>
> res/layout-large: multi-pane layout
>
> layout res/layout-sw600dp: multi-pane layout
>
> The last two files are identical, because one of them will be matched by Android 3.2 devices,
> and the other one is for the benefit of tablets and TVs with earlier
> versions of Android.
>
> **To avoid this duplication of the same file for tablets and TVs (and
> the maintenance headache resulting from it)**, you can use alias files.

So I need to make the layout-differencies in layouts with other names inside the `layout` folder; like `layout/mainnormal.xml` and `layout/mainlarge.xml`. Then I need to make `layout.xml` in different `values` folders, and make aliases as defined in the above [link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters).

For example I will need a `values/layout.xml` a `values-large-xhdpi-1280x800/layout.xml`(for galaxy Note) a `values-large/layout.xml` (for larger devices) and maybe also a `layout-sw600dp/layout.xml`.

In the first two I need to create aliases for `mainnormal.xml` and for the others for the `mainlarge.xml`. This way I won't need to know in code that which type one I'm using, just use an id, for example `R.layout.main`.

`layout.xml` in the first two case:

```
<resources>
    <item name="main" type="layout">@layout/mainnormal</item>
</resources>
```

In the latter cases:

```
<resources>
    <item name="main" type="layout">@layout/mainlarge</item>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, there are devices under 3.2 which I have to support

Not very many.

> Is there a way to force a device to choose from this folder, or to write over its variable (with java reflection? - I know that's pretty bad) to behave like normal screen not large?

No. However, you can find out the model numbers for those few devices and choose to load different layouts for them (e.g., `R.layout.main` normally, `R.layout.you_are_worrying_about_this_way_too_much` for few models of pre-API Level 13 7" tablets).

> is there a way to maintain only two xml package (folder): one for under-7inch-devices, and one for above-7inch devices

To be safe, I would go with three:

- `res/layout/` for below-7"
- `res/layout-sw600dp/` for 7" and up
- `res/layout-xlarge/`, perhaps using aliases to the ones in `res/layout-sw600dp/`, for the handful of XOOMs, Tab 10.1's, and such that didn't get upgraded to 3.2

Comment: Thanks, these three folders could work nice. Then the  only device I would need to cover is the 7inch-not-upgraded-galaxytab1, which will have a phone design by this (that would be fine by me, but customer will think other way).

Comment: However if I decide in code (with testing for inches) which layout to choose, I can load any layout, and don't let android to choose. Is that a bad choice? I feel it not too androidy, but this way I have full control over the layouts.

Comment: @abbath: "Is that a bad choice?" -- on the whole, yes, simply because there are *way* too many devices. Having a thousand-entry `switch` statement, even if you could find out details of all those devices, will be unmaintainable. To draw an analogy: user-agent sniffing in a Web app to provide workarounds for, say, IE6, is reasonable. Saying that you will try to catalog every version of every browser for every platform, to try to make your own mapping of browser to targeted Web content, is not normally done.

Comment: No, I thought I'd only check the devices' measures, and check whether if its under or above 7 inch. It's not a thousand-entry `switch` just a two-case thing which i have to check before the xml loading. Is that reasonable?

Comment: @abbath: So long as you are comfortable with the reliability of your calculations.

Comment: I think I found a solution which is not using any calculastions. Somehow I didn't notice that there's an other type of alias using for xml-s.

Answer (score 0):

Would making an alias resource help:
[Creating alias resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources)?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't make an alias named xyz.xml in `layout-large-xhdpi-1280x800` that refers to xyz.xml in `layout`, because it refers to self then (making infinite loop). I explain this further in Edit of OP

Comment: I found a solution and its with aliases, but not the type you linked.